# asp.net mvc3 persisting form data when user navigates to unrelated page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So a user fills out a form then decides to click on a unrelated link that happens to be on the page say to a disclaimer page. Then using internal site navigation (not the browser back button) comes back to the form he was on. The link back is an ActionLink.

What is the best way to keep his data on the form. I figure I'll have to serialize the data and save it. I can do a ajax call before going to the other page. I'm looking for the sexy solution. Something that will handle it on a global scale.

Is this even a standard practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is Stateless. You are trying to bring some Stateful nature it !

If you really want to keep the data, You can keep in the Session variable and access it there. You need to override the click event and (in javascript) send the form data to an action  via jQuery ajax post where you store it into Session. You can access it later when you come back to this page.

**Do you really want to do that ?** I think 80 % people knows that once they click on another link, the data will go away. You could probably show some alert message to ask "Are you sure to leave this page" like stackoverflow does.